# Not able to delete the text after using JavaScript Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, react-native

After using the replace to put a slash after the second character, I became unable to delete it.

[image: The code I'm using to make the replacement]

[image: Example of the problem]

Comment: that is what happens when you change the text as the user types. Get to 2 and it adds the slash. Is there a reason you are not using date input?

Comment: That is exactly what you do with your `replace`: you put the `/` back there.

Comment: Yeah, but I want to know how to change the Regex, so it will behave as I want

Comment: The issue is the reg exp is doing what you want as you type the date.... not sure how you can change it to do it both ways.  try moving the cursor and typing, you will run into other issues. You can listen for what key code is pressed and do thing differently

Comment: It's not a regex issue. You are over-aggressively acting upon user input.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus yeah, I know. But I would like to know how to change the regex to behave as I want

Comment: You're putting the cart in front of the horse. That's like asking how to super-cool a spatula in an effort to avoid burnt food.

Answer (score 2):

Use `event.key` to check for the pressed key, and if the key is either `Backspace` or `Delete` return from the event handler without executing the insertion of the `/`:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');

input.addEventListener('keydown', () => {
    if(event.key === 'Backspace' || event.key === 'Delete') {
       return;
    }  
    if(input.value.length === 2)    input.value += '/'; 
});
```

```html
<input>
```